# OLEObject does n't have Value property anymore (the code used to work before)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use autofill drop-down list in Excel

The code which i used.I got it from here

http://www.contextures.com/DataValComboboxClick.zip

All the sudden it stopped working (worked for 2 months before)

Now i am getting 438 error

> "Object does not support this property or method" in this line: .Value
>   = ""

The weird thing is that when i try to type the following in the immediate window: ?cbotemp.value, the promt shows me that cbotemp object does not have a Value property at all

Any help will be highly appreciated. I'm trying to work it out all night long and now it becomes desperate.

Here is the source code:

```
Option Explicit

' Developed by Contextures Inc.
' www.contextures.com

Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
'Hide combo box and move to next cell on Enter and Tab
Select Case KeyCode
Case 9
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
Case 13
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Case Else
    'do nothing
End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim str     As String
Dim cboTemp As OLEObject
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
On Error GoTo errHandler

If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
    Cancel = True
End If

Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
On Error Resume Next
With cboTemp
    .ListFillRange = ""
    .LinkedCell = ""
    .Visible = False
End With

On Error GoTo errHandler

If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    str = Target.Validation.Formula1
    str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)
    With cboTemp
        .Visible = True
        .Left = Target.Left
        .Top = Target.Top
        .Width = Target.Width + 15
        .Height = Target.Height + 5
        .ListFillRange = ws.Range(str).Address
        .LinkedCell = Target.Address
    End With
    cboTemp.Activate
    'open the drop down list automatically
    Me.TempCombo.DropDown
End If
errHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim str     As String
Dim cboTemp As OLEObject
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects("TempCombo")

On Error Resume Next

If cboTemp.Visible = True Then
    With cboTemp
        .Top = 10
        .Left = 10
        .ListFillRange = ""
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .Visible = False
        .Value = ""          'here i get 438 error
    End With
End If
errHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please post the code and point out the relevant line? I'm not going to download a random .zip file with macros enabled, and am not sure how others feel about it as well.

Comment: Bruce, 
i tried to post the source code but couldn't get sense of the editor interface
sorry, i should think about this kind of threat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in this part of code:

```
...
Dim cboTemp As OLEObject
...
  Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
    On Error Resume Next
  If cboTemp.Visible = True Then
    With cboTemp
      .Top = 10
      .Left = 10
      .ListFillRange = ""
      .LinkedCell = ""
      .Visible = False
      .Value = ""
    End With
  End If
```

Since `cboTemp` is of type `OLEObject` it really has not a property `Value`. But the `On Error Resume Next` should prevent this error from breaking the program.

If this is not (or not more) the case, then the setting in:

VBA Editor - `Tools > Options > General > Error Trapping`

is set to `Break on all errors`.

Default is `Break on unhandled errors`.

Set it back to default or simply do not set `.Value=""` at all. It is not necessary.

Comment: Axel! Thanks a lot! How stupid of me. I changed error handling option and it worked! I wouldn't expect this source to post a faulty code. Obviously i was wrong :(